# Cloudsim: Update VM

Tags: java, cloudsim

I am working on an algorithm to select the `VM` for deploying the `Cloudlet(task)`. 
Now, I need to update the **VM's** current allocated ram whenever a **cloudlet** finished it's execution.

I don't know where I need to do this.

I tried this in `processCloudletReturn()` method in `DataCenterbroker` class

> but it is called only after all cloudlets are submitted to the VMs.

**I need to update the VM's Ram whenever a cloudlet executed successfully.**

*For, ex:*

Let us consider, I have 100 tasks to be deployed and now I submitted 20 tasks then, before submitting 21st task if 1st task finishes its execution I need to update the corresponding **VM**.

Can anyone help me..
Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as below:

```
for(Cloudlet cloudlet: getCloudletSubmittedList()){
        if(!finishedCloudlets.contains(cloudlet) && cloudlet.isFinished()){
        Vm vm = getVmsCreatedList().get(cloudlet.getVmId()-1);                        
        vm.setCurrentAllocatedRam(vm.getCurrentAllocatedRam() - (int)(cloudlet.getUtilizationOfRam(CloudSim.clock())*100));
        vm.updateVmProcessing(CloudSim.clock(), null);
        finishedCloudlets.add(cloudlet);
    }
}
```

where you can check whether already submitted tasks are finished if so you can update your VM.